# Queryset, get only one of reverse relationships

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = CharField
    createdat = DateTimeField

class Bar(models.Model):
    rel = ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')
    createdat = DateTimeField
```

`Foo.prefetch_related('bars').all()` gives me all Bars. Are there any way I can only get the latest `Bar` for each `Foo`, using only one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `Prefetch` object, which is [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related).

`Prefetch()` lets you filter the query, like so in your example:

```
queryset = Bar.objects.latest('createdat')
latest_bars = Foo.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'bars', 
        queryset, 
        to_attr="latest_bar"
    )
)
the_latest_bar_for_first_foo = latest_bars[0].latest_bar
```

Comment: Actually, this does not work. `latest()` doesn't return a queryset but an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A.prefetch_related('bars').latest()
```

Comment: This is going to give me the latest of the `A`s (one result row), which is not what I want. I want all the results, with the latest `Bar` for each `Foo`.